# Git Undo Merge but Not delete later commits

Tags: git, merge

My problem is: 
I'm currently working on master branch. 
My colleague merge his branch to master at B. 
Then I continue my working with serveral commits C, D, E. 
After that, I found that the merge should have not been there. And I want to revert the merge but still keep C, D, E.
**Any suggestion???**

Sample here:

```
0--A--B--C--D--E
      /
  G--H
```

And this is what I want it to be:

```
0--A--C--D--E
```

Comment: Checkout A and cherry-pick C to E perhaps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Reverting

You should be able to do a git revert:

```
git checkout master
git revert B -m <mainline>
```

Where `mainline` is an integer which defines the branch to use as the main one. You can easily deduct which one to use by typing

```
git log B
```

You should see something like:

```
commit B
Merge: A H
```

And then your mainline is `1` if you want to revert to state `A`, or `2` if you want to revert to state `H`.

In this case you would write:

```
git revert B -m 1
```

This will create a new commit with the B commit removed. Your history will now look like:

```
0--A--B--C--D--E--F
```

Where the `F` commit is actually an undo of `B`.

As it says in the [git-revert manpage](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html), it is useful to check the [Revert a faulty merge How-To](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt).

## Rebasing

Another option is to do:

```
git checkout master
git rebase -i A
```

however this will change you git history and might not be what you want, especially if other people are working on the same repository.

A new editor will popup with something like:

```
pick A
pick G
pick H
pick C
pick D
pick E
```

And you should change it to:

```
pick A
drop G
drop H
pick C
pick D
pick E
```

Save the file and exit the editor to continue the rebase process.

Your history should now look like `0--A--C--D--E`.

## Cherry-picking

Or you can create a new branch and cherry pick the commits you want:

```
git checkout A
git checkout -b new-master
git cherry-pick C..E
```

Comment: you can't revert a merge commit with the command you provided

Comment: You're right, I've just updated the answer with the correct command.